# What is the problem in this code that redistributes characters to make all strings equal?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to solve the following problem:

> You are given an array of strings words (0-indexed).
>
> In one operation, pick two distinct indices `i` and `j`, where
> `words[i]` is a non-empty string, and move any character from
> `words[i]` to any position in `words[j]`.
>
> Return `true` if you can make every string in words equal using any
> number of operations, and `false` otherwise.

But it doesn't seem to work the way I expect.  Can someone help point out my error?

```
bool makeEqual(vector<string>& words)
{ 
    int n = words.size();
    map<char, int> mp;
 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        string s = words[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) //<-- what is problem here?
        {
            mp(s[j])++;
        }
     }

     set<int> st;
     for(auto it : mp)
     {
         st.insert(it.second);
     }
     return st.size() == 1;
}
```

Comment: @molbdnilo My best guess is "problem"

Comment: Based on the title, I thought this was a question about the Portable Bitmap image format.

Comment: Your code says that "a" and "b" can be made equal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your program is not the part that you have marked.  It is the logic that follows that loop.

It looks like your strategy to solve the problem is to count how many times each character appears.  That is a reasonable start.  From there, it should follow that to satisfy the problem, each character must be able to appear exactly the same number of times in every word.  And so, every count *must* be a multiple of `n`.

To check if a value `x` is a multiple of `n` you can use the modulo operator:

```
if (x % n == 0) std::cout << x << " is a multiple of " << n << "\n";
```

And so, you should now see that the actual problem is the very last statement in your function:

```
return st.size() == 1;
```

What that does is say that all characters appear exactly the same number of times.  However, it's not even correct in the simplest case because you still haven't checked that value is a multiple of `n`.  And it doesn't handle characters that can appear different number of times (*e.g.* if all words became "eel" it would fail).

So what you actually need is to test that all of the character counts are the correct multiple.  You can use [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) from `<algorithm>` to help with this:

```
bool makeEqual(const vector<string>& words)
{ 
    int n = words.size();
    map<char, int> mp;
 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        const string& s = words[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
        {
            mp(s[j])++;
        }
    }

    // Return true if all character counts are a multiple of n
    return all_of(mp.begin(), mp.end(),
        [n](const pair<char, int>& cc) {
            return cc.second % n == 0;
        });
}
```

If you struggle with lambda syntax, this is basically equivalent to:

```
for (const auto& cc : mp)
{
    if (cc.second % n != 0) return false;
}
return true;
```